# website on mobile is larger than the display

Tags: css, html, mobile

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [website in mobile larger than display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11165050/website-in-mobile-larger-than-display)

I've realized this website: agriandgolf.com

Unfortunally on the mobile devices (I tryed with a samsung galaxy 2) the website is larger than the display.

I have to **zoom out on each loaded page**.

Of course i've used

```
<meta id='viewport' name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes'/>
<meta name='mobileoptimized' content='0'>
```

I've used html5

Comment: You haven't provided a whole lot of context.  I personally don't think it's worth a -1 (you have posted the most relevant bits of code) but most people like to see that you've done some research into the issue, perhaps highlighting a few more places in your code that you think could have caused the unexpected behavior.

Comment: Thank you Sandy, I'll give to this more attention in future. Of course I've searched for days, in this forum and also in other portals. Regarding the 'few more places', unfortunally I can't imagine what else in my website could give this behaviour (of course I've some images and divs, everything wrappend in a fixed 960px layout).

Comment: Well, one thing you may want to consider is the CSS property [`overflow`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp).  If you have any elements that force your width over the viewport (such as an image, or a div that stacks outwards too far), it will override that meta tag and cause scrolling.  It's a bit of a hack, though to just slap `overflow: hidden` on and call it a day.  I strongly encourage you to use it to find the issue.

Comment: I didn't use any div/images with a width or position out of my layout, but maybe, jquery crosslide did! But exscuse me, i didn't understand. where do i put `code`overflow: hidden`code`?

Comment: It's CSS (I linked to a description on the word overflow, it's a little hard to see in the `code box`'s grey background).  Here's the link again: [link](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp).  Overflow controls how an element handles content bigger (or outside) of itself.  `overflow: hidden` simply crops it.  So, for example, if you have an image that is 640x480 px in a `div` that's only 100x100 px with `overflow: hidden` only the top left 100x100 px region of the image will be visible.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing your viewport tag to this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes" />
```

And maybe get rid of that IE specific mobileoptimized tag or change its value to "width" and see if that helps.

Comment: It doesn't work. Thank you for the suggestion anyway.

Comment: Your site is working fine on my iPhone 4 now :)

Comment: Thank you very much for verifying! in my Galaxy S2 it doesn't show correctly, despite of lots of tests